# Windows C Drive error - Fault Module Name: ffdshow.ax

Tags: windows-explorer, ffdshow

> Problem Event Name: APPCRASH Application
>
> Name: explorer.exe
>
> Application Version: 6.1.7600.16385
>
> Application Timestamp: 4a5bc60d
>
> Fault Module Name: ffdshow.ax
>
> Fault Module Version: 1.1.3882.0 Fault
>
> Module Timestamp: 4df77fa1
>
> Exception Code: c0000005
>
> Exception Offset: 0019d19b

This mostly happen where IDM downloaded files are present.

Answer (score 1):

The ffdshow module suggests that it may be caused by that module trying to get your movie file's snapshot/thumbnail when you open up a folder with movie files in explorer.

May be you could try to disable snapshot/thumbnail preview and see?

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the K Lite Codec pack software and all is well.

If this does not work, try downloading and installing ffddshow:

http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/download.php